# Is it ok to change motherboard and cpu on Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-13.04

I have Ubuntu server 13.04 and I need to replace motherboard and CPU. Is it OK to do so, or should I make clean install of Ubuntu server after HW replacement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be ok.....just make sure you have appropriate modules compiled and available for all the drivers on the new board.